# What dictates the tags appended to 'Not the answer you're looking for?'

Tags: discussion, tags

Can a tag edit be devised to have a tag removed from being automatically appended to the list following 'Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged ...'?

Specifically, the bottom of every Excel question page holds this footer.

[image: Not the Answer you were looking for]

All one has to do is hover over the [macros](/questions/tagged/macros) tag to be informed that the tag is:

> Not for MS-OFFICE / VBA / macro languages. Use the respective tags instead.

I went into the tag edit screen to see if I could find some cross-association that could be readily removed. While there is mention of [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) and similar tags, the purpose is to warn against cross-pollination; not encourage it.

So what dictates the [macros](/questions/tagged/macros) inclusion in the closing blurb? Can a normal user edit away its inclusion? If it is a strictly back-end automated procedure, is there a fudge file that lists false-positives that should not follow the rule?

Comment: I assume it's just statistical cross-referencing: what tags most commonly show up with the tags in this question? The eventual solution to that is the steady cleanup that's been progressing for a long while now on that tag.

Comment: I've always thought that it was just the tags currently on the question that appeared at the bottom. Do you have a link to the one you've screencapped?

Comment: @jimsug -That's the answer! I didn't notice that the tags were identical to the ones added to the question but I've just checked and that is indeed the case. In fact, a tag edit that removes [tag:macros] coupled with an F5 refresh immediately removed the tag from the bottom list. Post this as an answer and I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the tags that the question is tagged with - look at this question, for example!

I'd put more in this to prevent it coming up in the VLQ post queue, but there's not much more to be said ;)

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't take much to say everything that needs to be said. Thank you!